# Paint DataGridView ColumnHeader with it's default gradient styles

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView setup similar to the one on the left. I have some amount of columns that are used for images to show statuses / errors. This works fine. My issue is that I don't really like the look of having each column divided into sections for those columns. Ideally I would like to have the column headers paint as if they are one column header so it looks like the one on right.

Is there a way to do this using some internal DataGridView rendering methods that I don't know of?

[image]

I tried to look through the DataGridView code in Reflector to see where it actually does it's column header painting but I couldn't find anything. I figured I might be able to copy what it is doing and just extend the cell bounds to cover each of those first 4 columns.

Summary:

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Override the `CellPainting` event for the -1 `RowIndex` and paint it as you desire.

Alternatively, you can create a new class that inherits from `DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell` and override the paint method for that, but there's some other steps (that I don't remember offhand) you have to do to get the grid to use your derived class which is kind of a pain.

Edit:

Here's a link that explains it better: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/74959006-7a8a-4487-ab54-f2aac2bf7196/custom-paint-of-datagridview-column-headers

Some excerpts in case the link dies:

In the paint override, you'll do something like this:

```
if (e.RowIndex == -1)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, e.CellBounds);
    e.Paint(e.ClipBounds, (DataGridViewPaintParts.All & ~DataGridViewPaintParts.Background));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

If you go with the class override, keep in mind all of this:

> If you create your own class, then you can either a) set the column's
>   HeaderCell property to an instance of your custom header class (you'll
>   might want to copy some of the properties such as Text from the header
>   cell that currently exists before overwriting the value). You can also
>   create a custom column class that sets the HeaderCell to your custom
>   cell in the constructor.
>
> If you want to do this for all columns, handle the ColumnAdded event
>   so you know when you need to set your custom header cell.

All of this in the Edit portion of my answer is attributable to Mark Rideout in the link above, the DataGridView program manager in at least 2006.